# Проблема с pydub: hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args, FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл

Tags: python-3.8

Вот мой код:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
AudioSegment.converter = 'C:/Users/ 
                               Админ/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python38/site-packages/ffmpeg'
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3("Musics/Music.mp3")
sound.export("Musics/Music.wav", format="wav")
```

Вроде всё верно но питон всё равно выдаёт ошибку.

---

Вот ошибка:

```
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args, FileNotFoundError: 
[WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
```

Возможно я не правильно указал путь у ffmpeg. Ну тогда другой вопрос где он ещё может находится?

Comment: Отформатируйте код и ошибку, добавьте метку python, сделайте вопрос читаемым короче [ask]

Comment: Код исправил, как вы и сказали.

Comment: Тут есть специальное форматирование для кода, посмотрите внимательно в редакторе, для ошибки можно использовать цитирование, ну и метку языка python вы не добавили

Comment: А вы знаете в чём проблема?

Comment: Возможно, неправильно указали первый путь => почему бы не использовать модуль `pathlib`? Возможно, неправильно указали второй и третий путь => вы уверены что рабочая директория именно такая, что в ней есть нужная директория и файл?

Comment: Pathlib просто меняем расширение а мне нужна именно конвертация

Comment: скорее всего он у вас ругается на наличие кириллице в пути к приложению. У меня аналогичная ошибка, но насколько я знаю проблема возникает когда в path сидит не латинские знаки